# Make 1s using a bunch of 1s

Tags: number-theory, atomic-code-golf

Your task is to form an expression equaling \$ 11111111111 \text{ (11 ones)} \$ using only the following characters: `1+()`. Keep in mind that the result is in base 10, and not some other base like binary. Of course, these expressions should follow the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).
 Furthermore, the only operations which should be performed are addition, multiplication, and exponentation.

Some examples of valid expressions include

$$ 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 $$
$$ (1 + 1)(1 + 1) = 4 $$
$$ (1 + 1)^{1 + 1 + 1} = 8 $$
$$ 1 + (1 + 1(1 + 1)^{1 + 1^{1 + 1}}) = 6 $$

Some examples of *invalid* expressions include

$$ 11 + 11 \quad | \quad \text{concatenation of ones}$$
$$ 1 + ((1) \quad | \quad \text{unbalanced parentheses} $$
$$ \displaystyle\binom{1}{1 + 1} \quad | \quad \text{disallowed operation} $$

### Scoring

After forming an expression which equals \$ 11111111111 \$, your score will be calculated by the sum of the \$ \text{no. of 1} \$, the \$ \text{no. of +} \$, and the \$ \text{no. of} \$ pairs of parentheses. For example, \$ (1 + 1)(1 + 1)^{1 + (1)} \$ has a score of \$ 12 \$, because it has \$ 6 \$ \$ 1 \$s, \$ 3 \$ pluses, and \$ 3 \$ pairs of parentheses.

The submission with the lowest score wins!

Comment: to be clear, is the trivial solution 11111111111 is forbidden? :D and slightly longer variants like +11111111111, (11111111111) etc.

Comment: @innisfree - the rules clearly say concatenation isn't valid, meaning you can't even have 11, let alone 11111111111.

Comment: Oh now I see, but I don’t think it’s that clearly stated

Comment: It's clear (it's the first example of an invalid expression), it's just a bit weirdly stated, since "concatenation" wouldn't normally be thought of as an operation.

Comment: @steve and also weirdly stated  because `1+1`, which is allowed, is also a concatenation of `1`, `+` and `1`.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe better to write it as "using only the number 1, the + operator, and parentheses".

Comment: This is apparently causing some controversy, so I went ahead and edited it be more clear.

Comment: Is base 2 allowed?

Comment: @S.S. Anne base 2 is not allowed, only base 10 please

Comment: @dingledooper You should make that explicit. I just spent half an hour on a binary answer.

Comment: @S.S. Anne Sorry about that :( I've made it explicit now.

Comment: After spending rather too much computer time, I thought I would share that the optimal answer seems to be in the range [50,69] operations. 50, because my brute force optimizer has excluded everything with 49 or fewer operations, 69 because we have a constructive example of that being possible, below. The solver, for the record, is here (https://gist.github.com/imallett/35b95dc1b4535b6b3c35b642029add17), and can doubtless be improved or used for partial results.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## score = <s>82</s> <s>71</s> 69 (34 ‘1’s + 23 ‘+’s + 12 parenthesis pairs)

$$\begin{multline*}
11111111111 = 1 + (1 + 1) \cdot {}
\\
(1 + 1 + 1 + (1 + 1)^{(1 + 1)^{1 + 1 + 1}}(1 + ((1 + 1)(1 + 1 + 1))^{1 + 1 + 1})) \cdot {}
\\
(1 + (1 + (1 + 1 + 1)^{1 + 1})^{1 + (1 + 1)^{1 + 1}})
\end{multline*}$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9RCoMwDIbfPUXoi4kdA9nzbjIG4joUREvrxoYUdoztel7EtVG36R6ahu//85Poe1s09W5QN21gD3EcH4YUJGAoKY3f9CZ27D7NR3WOGf6N0cJFo/ItiyA3Nct452jwa0XalHWL6ppVGJbdGqWrLFcojp3YgEgSFPSFLjD6JYSMgo0oampl/b2clDcXnyxSQVF2Oq2x9FhnRtVrAYPAS52FzRujvN5xrgTOkTDOOUDmDvrHM@0fryB1wcJEzmR2898WypbW96Wx/o7hDQ)

#### Search program in [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)

This finds optimal solutions for up to about 8 digit numbers.  Don’t try it on anything larger—it will eat all your memory.

I constructed the above solution by manually writing \$11111111111 = 1 + 111110 \cdot 100001\$ and searching for optimal solutions to \$111110\$ and \$100001\$.

```rust
use std::env;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Op {
    One,
    Add(u32, u32),
    Mul(u32, u32),
    Pow(u32, u32),
}

fn show(ops: &[Option<Op>], z: u32, prec: u32) {
    match ops[z as usize].as_ref().unwrap() {
        Op::One => print!("1"),
        Op::Add(x, y) => {
            if prec > 0 {
                print!("(");
            }
            show(ops, *x, 0);
            print!(" + ");
            show(ops, *y, 0);
            if prec > 0 {
                print!(")");
            }
        }
        Op::Mul(x, y) => {
            if prec > 1 {
                print!("(");
            }
            show(ops, *x, 1);
            show(ops, *y, 1);
            if prec > 1 {
                print!(")");
            }
        }
        Op::Pow(x, y) => {
            if prec > 2 {
                print!("(");
            }
            show(ops, *x, 3);
            print!("^{{");
            show(ops, *y, 0);
            print!("}}");
            if prec > 2 {
                print!(")");
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for target in env::args().skip(1).map(|arg| arg.parse().unwrap()) {
        let mut ops: Vec<Option<Op>> = vec![None; target as usize + 1];
        let mut vs: Vec<Vec<u32>> = vec![];
        while !ops[target as usize].is_some() {
            let mut v: Vec<u32> = vec![];
            let mut visit = |x, op| {
                if let Some(x) = x {
                    if x <= target {
                        if ops[x as usize].is_none() {
                            ops[x as usize] = Some(op);
                            v.push(x);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            let level = vs.len();
            let score = level / 2;
            match level % 2 {
                0 => {
                    if score == 1 {
                        visit(Some(1), Op::One);
                    }
                    for i in 1..score.saturating_sub(1) {
                        let j = score - 1 - i;
                        for u in &vs[i * 2..i * 2 + 2] {
                            for v in &vs[j * 2..j * 2 + 2] {
                                for &x in u {
                                    for &y in v {
                                        visit(x.checked_pow(y), Op::Pow(x, y));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for i in 1..score {
                        let j = score - i;
                        for u in &vs[i * 2 - 1..i * 2 + 1] {
                            for v in &vs[j * 2 - 2..j * 2 + 1] {
                                for &x in u {
                                    for &y in v {
                                        visit(x.checked_mul(y), Op::Mul(x, y));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                1 => {
                    for i in 1..score.saturating_sub(1) {
                        let j = score - 1 - i;
                        for u in &vs[i * 2..i * 2 + 2] {
                            for v in &vs[j * 2..j * 2 + 2] {
                                for &x in u {
                                    for &y in v {
                                        visit(x.checked_add(y), Op::Add(x, y));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
            vs.push(v);
        }
        print!("{} = ", target);
        show(&ops, target, 0);
        println!();
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VfbbtpAEH3nKwaqIjslLiZvJiBV7WtLpUp9QRQ5ZoFNjG15vQ4E/Ot1Z40XfA2gpFIjdaUQ2D0zO5cz47HPWRDHnBFgwcwwiBP2G4134xnxaUiUz7brkA58IXd8oU4axOErGHmwbQCuER4lXz7NZgq/6XUAP9T91lduF7e@u4/ZrajRmDvAlrjresyA9njkBdR1bkfecNKBJwMSsOcTK/mqpreuzMBaAoqMn8BkwBl9IhPNZFOfzBVV486jb3qKRCd2eoaBtsJgiNqoEzSVlt5KjZLnwoV1BzaqQB1FxaLzxAgYQrdwIpbUqLTUfu4wyv2SfnbgCq/pFrBSCXyAopqM4KYseJ5tar1tUS4KImsno6C/VhT0Z13Va13VX8NVwcaTrvZey9WbmoT/2m4vS7gUjKJWbXx6L4lPlBbmyqTOoYrmrg@B6S9IANQB7BGGgb8Ylht7oJ6iq9oKa26HezvAD80zfUYyxZitRhuVrHgASdH/JNbtseyHMICQWM3xN@w6fXmjLHIsDn3SL@kJUzXiD9vEUUkG@7ikNoGmaBoFpRONsilzVyTXMXL69@qF6grNOSRlNEDMDhPueruKLGCOBPiHuG@NzIN1BSgFruF2IENQDUqBwqt13iEH41dyqLgKcmhNYpfrFRhSXKHmcbZE@@thUeO83fxOVA6rTUJii7AzzSbIxzKCWa6PrT1FfoReHrJ/WuwP31dWRrfcADLBTdUPKpvOISIi8UoSPV3tyOdNTXyqYyMqjIri0jUtuVNjZsB9M6DOYsr4HSp@xgARiHsMwt7aazT2Gmh9esRlXFzWDtmYwhX0NC35hyXWm5ygjRAOpfD9Xvj@XGGpoL0WGvgZ6IPERkiEZ0ocs7LWrCWxHshs6mFf3aTpOXT/E1x/PmnnI6IXl0olSS6gxEV0EBQ6UkK/nBKoIEML/V@mxQpnHkmLw/zzZmhR3tHr@9n/JvPX2WTie4Rk0@Gd4g2zaSrYxB2fmNbSvLNJU8m8OJVF8DmdDAdhxuUjQg6h2whp1Oqk000Gmsy@7WT43Z/lB@BE3naacg7AWTWOY12sbqx3cem/rbltLlh8PfoD)

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+%2B+%281+%2B+1%29%5E%28%281+%2B+1%29%5E%281+%2B+1%29%29%281+%2B+%281+%2B+1%29%281+%2B+%281+%2B+%281+%2B+1%29%5E%281+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281+%2B+1%29%29%29%281+%2B+%281+%2B+1+%2B+%281+%2B+1+%2B+1%29%5E%281+%2B+1%29%29%281+%2B+1+%2B+%28%28%281+%2B+1%29%281+%2B+1+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281+%2B+1+%2B+1%29%29%29). Do you have some generating code to post?

Comment: Is it expected that your program's solution for `111110` is worse than just doubling its solution for `55555`?

Comment: @Neil I fixed that a while ago, you must be using an old version.

Answer (score 15):

## By hand -  <s>118 112 111</s>  82

$$(1+(1+1)^{(1+1)^{1+1}}(1+(1+1)(1+(1+(1+1)^{1+1})^{1+1})^{1+1}))(1+(1+1+(1+1+1)^{1+1})(1+1+(((1+1)(1+1+1))^{1+1})^{1+1+1}))$$

**[Try it at Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%28%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%29%2B%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%28%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%29%2B%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%28%28%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%2B%28%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%29%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%29%2B2%29%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%2B1%2B1)**

This was found by working my way down from \$11111111111\$ looking for close divisibility considering factors which are close in construction to powers and is:

$$(((8(9^4)+(3(9^2))+8)((16+1)^2)+8)81+2)9+2$$

There are \$16\$ parentheses pairs, \$40\$ ones, and \$26\$ additions.

---

Previous @**111**

$$((1+1)(1+1+1)^{1+1})^{(1+1)^{1+1+1}}+((1+1)(1+1+1)^{1+1}(1+1+1+1+1)^{1+1})^{1+1+1}+((1+1+1)^{1+1+1})^{1+1+1}+((1+1)(1+1+1)^{1+1})^{1+1+1}+(1+1)((1+1+1)^{1+1}+1)$$

**[Try it at Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%5E%28%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%2B%28%281%2B1%29*%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29*%28%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%2B%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%2B%28%28%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%2B%281%2B1%29%28%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%2B1%29)**

This is
$$18^8+450^3+(3^3)^3+18^3+20$$
Where:
\$18 = 2\times 9 = (1+1)(1+1+1)^{1+1}\$
\$8 = 2^3 = (1+1)^{1+1+1}\$
\$450 = 18\times 25 = (1+1)(1+1+1)^{1+1}(1+1+1+1+1)^{1+1}\$
\$20 = 2\times (9+1) = (1+1)((1+1+1)^{1+1}+1)\$

Answer (score 13):

## 69 operations

$$1+(1+((1+1+1)^{1+1}+1)^{1+1+1+1+1})(1+1)\\
\cdot(1+1+1+(1+((1+1+1)(1+1))^{1+1+1})(1+1)^{(1+1)^{1+1+1}})$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9fCsIwDMbfd4rSlyWrCMNnbyKDMisbjK20U5RS2DH0el5kpplDGemf8Pu@pKl9jM3QH2Zzt04cRZ7np7lUQIs2BVaBzrgmS0RMIi6OfzPj1fl1VQHKX3mMONMjmXVtP4K56Q7S03tnbKdrA7IKcidkUYDEH4yJ4T9BYJRsiNnQG0/Tc6d6uFJnWUrM9Pm8xYqw1c70WwGSwENdpK8HZ0gP3FcJ7qPEUhcFMI/iPT3L9/RKUkgWJmolq5vvsTG@9ZS3ztM/5g8)

Verifier thanks to @AndersKaseorg

34 `1`s, 24 `+`s, 11 `()`s.

Decomposition, by layers:

- 11111111111 = 100001 * 111110 + 1
- 100001 = 10^5+1
- 111110 = 55555*2
- 55555 = 3 + 217*256
- 217 = 6^3+1
- 256 = 2^2^3

I wrote a program to brute-force this, but I'm still working on the program.

Comment: I guess 111110 = 6 + 217*512 results in the same number of operations.

Comment: You don't need the dot there. It's implicit.

Answer (score 10):

#### score = 22222222221

The sequence $$1 + 1 +\ ... 1$$ where `...` is 11111111108 pairs of `1 +`. I think I can probably shorten this, though.

Answer (score 8):

## Score:  <s>113</s>  111

Breakdown:

- ones: \$56\$
- plus signs: \$45\$
- pairs of parentheses: \$10\$
- no multiplication

The expression below is in JS syntax, with \$p^q\$ computed as `p**[q]`.

```
(((1+1)**[1+1+1+1]+1+1)**[1+1+1+1]+((1+1)**[1+1+1+1]+1)**[1+1]+((1+1+1)**[1+1]+1+1+1)**[1+1])**[1+1]+((1+1+1+1+1+1)**[1+1+1]+(1+1)**[1+1+1+1])**[1+1]+1+1+1+1+1+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e@nYPtfQ0PDUNtQU0srGkiBYKw2Oh@LCigPKofER@Ghq0KRBYujGYxqDAT@T87PK87PSdXLyU/X8NP8DwA)

### Formula

$$(((1+1)^{1+1+1+1}+1+1)^{1+1+1+1}+((1+1)^{1+1+1+1}+1)^{1+1}+((1+1+1)^{1+1}+1+1+1)^{1+1})^{1+1}+((1+1+1+1+1+1)^{1+1+1}+(1+1)^{1+1+1+1})^{1+1}+1+1+1+1+1+1$$

which simplifies down to:

$$\big((2^4+2)^4+(2^4+1)^2+(3^2+3)^2\big)^2+(6^3+2^4)^2+6$$
$$=(18^4+17^2+12^2)^2+232^2+6$$
$$=105409^2+232^2+6$$
$$=11111057281+53824+6$$
$$=11111111111$$

Comment: 111 is an apt score :)

Answer (score 4):

## Score 92 (46 1's, 33 +'s, 13 parentheses)

$$((1+1)(1+1+1)^{1+1})^{(1+1)^{1+1+1}}$$

$$+$$

$$((1+1)^{(1+1)(1+1+1)^{1+1}}+((1+1+1+1+1)(1+1+1)(1+1+1+1))^{1+1}+1)$$

$$*$$

$$(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)^{1+1+1}$$

`18^8 + (2^18+60^2+1) * 7^3`

`18^8 + 91,150,535` Similar to Jonathan Allen but I factorize the 91,150,535.

**[Try at wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%7B1%2B1%7D%29%5E%7B%281%2B1%29%5E%7B1%2B1%2B1%7D%7D%2B%28%281%2B1%29%5E%7B%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%7B1%2B1%7D%7D%2B%28%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%29%5E%7B1%2B1%7D%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%5E%7B1%2B1%2B1%7D)**

**Check calculation Link to TIO, Ruby language** (wolfram alpha website is playing up for me)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBQ8NQ21BTC0SCaDBDE0RrIPggEW24AFYNEGltqKAGCg01EEQjC2ojmwBk/P8PAA)

Comment: You have a typo (twice) -- 91,150,**5**35. Also, I think you have 30 rather than 60. Other than that I think this will be crushing :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan yeah typing this up is almost as hard as solving it! I was already working on the `18^8` when I saw your answer, but you got it out first.

Comment: With the fix I think it's 92 - [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%5E%28%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%2B%28%281%2B1%29%5E%28%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%29%2B%28%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%29%5E%281%2B1%29%2B1%29%28%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29)

Answer (score 3):

## 135 = 67 '1's + 49 '+'s + 19 parens

1st attempt with manual calculator fiddling:

[image]

#### Method

- 11111111111 = 21649*513239
- 21649 = 1 + ((2^4)*3*11*41)
- 513239 = 1 + (2*11*41*569)
- 569 = 2 + (3^4)*7
- then the small numbers are built up manually

[Try it on Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%2B%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%281%2B%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%29%281%2B%281%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%2B%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%281%2B%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%29%29%281%2B1%2B%281%2B1%2B1%29%5E%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%281%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%2B1%29%29%29)

Answer (score 1):

## Score <s>115</s> <s>97</s> 93

\$ ((1+1)^{(1+1+1)^{1+1+1}}+((1+1+1)^{1+1+1}+1+1)((1+1+1)^{1+1}(((1+1)^{(1+1)^{1+1}}+1)^{1+1+1}+1+1+1+1+1)+1))((1+1+1)^{1+1+1+1}+1)+1 = (2^{3^3}+(3^3+2)(3^2((2^{2^2}+1)^3+5)+1))(3^4+1)+1 = (2^{27}+29(9(17^3+5)+1)))(82)+1 = (2^{27}+29(44263))(82)+1 = 135501355(82)+1 = 11111111111\$

Found by using @AndersKaseorg's Rust program to generate a solution for \$ 44263 \$. (I was using an old version of his program when I created my previous answer; the current version also finds this answer when I plug in \$ 1283627 \$.)

Answer (score 1):

## Score 187 (87 `1`s, 68 `+`s, 32 `()` pairs)

$$\begin{multline*}
\left(1+1\right)\left(1+1+1+1+1\right)\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1\right)}+1+1+1\right)
\\
\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1+1+1\right)}+\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1\right)}+1\right)
\\
\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1\right)}\right)}+\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1\right)}+1+1+1+1+1+1+1\right)
\\
\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1\right)}+1+1+1+1+1\right)}+\left(1+1\right)^{\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1\right)}+1\right)}
\right. \\ \left. {}
+\left(1+1\right)^{\left(\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1\right)}\right)}+\left(1+1\right)^{\left(1+1+1+1+1+1+1\right)}+1+1+1\right)+1
\end{multline*}$$

[Try it online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ezzk4gllap)

Based on the fact that $$11111111110 = 2×5×11×41×271×9091$$ The formula is that, based on powers of two.

Comment: this could be optimized a fair bit, for example you could replace each instance of `(1+1)^(1+1+1) + 1` with `(1+1+1)^(1+1)` and subtract 2 from your score each time -
EDIT: you also don't need the parentheses in the exponents

Comment: @Sagittarius I do need them: without them the exponents are done in the wrong order.

Comment: how would that make a difference if there is only one exponent? I've seen other people leave them out

Comment: @Sagittarius Oh, yes for some parts. Honestly, I'd forgotten about this ages ago.